# MySQL query to return what has not been signed in a table no longer working

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables `wp_policy` & `wp_policies`

`wp_policy` contains a list of policies and wp_policies contains which user has signed what policy.

I need to show depending on what user is selected, what that user has not signed.

the below was working until more than one person signed a policy(indicating a problem with the query).

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_policy.Policy_Name, wp_policies.PolicyID
FROM wp_policy
LEFT JOIN wp_policies ON wp_policy.Policy_ID = wp_policies.PolicyID
WHERE wp_policies.Username =  'Jbyrne'
OR wp_policies.Username IS NULL 
AND wp_policy.Policy_ID IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY wp_policy.Policy_Name ASC
```

Example: **wp_policy**:
**Policy_Name|           |Policy_ID**
Adverse Weather Conditions|           |Adverse_Weather_Conditionsv1
Bank Holiday Policy|           |Bank_Holiday_Policyv1
Breaks|           |Breaksv2
Collections Policy|           |Collections_Policyv1
Company Car Share Policy|           |Company_Car_Share_Policyv1
Smoking Policy|           |Smoking_Policyv2
Whistleblowing Policy|           |Whistleblowing_Policyv1

Example: **wp_policies**
**PolicyName|          |Username|           PolicyID**
Adverse Weather Conditions|           Jbyrne|           Adverse_Weather_Conditionsv1
Whistleblowing Policy|           Jbyrne|           Whistleblowing_Policyv1
Company Car Share Policy|           Barrowc|           Company_Car_Share_Policyv1
Bank Holiday Policy|           Barrowc|           Bank_Holiday_Policyv1

I need to see what 'Jbyrne' has not signed

which should show:

Bank_Holiday_Policyv1
Breaksv2
Collections_Policyv1
Company_Car_Share_Policyv1
Smoking_Policyv2

Comment: can you add an example and wished result ?

Comment: Certainly bear with me a second

Comment: you need all the users name with the policy he has taken.... if none has take any policy you need Query for this case

Comment: echo_me please see revised above

Comment: you should have stuck with my edit. it was much more comprehensible, and it had an appropriate title.

Comment: I stuck with the edit. Not the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that RIGHT JOINs tend to be regarded as less intuitive than LEFT JOINs. It's for this reason, I think, that LEFT JOINs dominate...

```
 CREATE TABLE policy(policy_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,policy_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

 INSERT INTO policy VALUES
 ('Adverse Weather Conditions','Adverse_Weather_Conditionsv1'),
 ('Bank Holiday Policy','Bank_Holiday_Policyv1'),
 ('Breaks','Breaksv2'),
 ('Collections Policy','Collections_Policyv1'),
 ('Company Car Share Policy','Company_Car_Share_Policyv1'),
 ('Smoking Policy','Smoking_Policyv2'),
 ('Whistleblowing Policy','Whistleblowing_Policyv1');

 CREATE TABLE user_policy(username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,policy_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(username,policy_id));

 INSERT INTO user_policy VALUES
 ('Jbyrne','Adverse_Weather_Conditionsv1'),
 ('Jbyrne','Whistleblowing_Policyv1'),
 ('Barrowc','Company_Car_Share_Policyv1'),
 ('Barrowc','Bank_Holiday_Policyv1');

 SELECT p.*
   FROM policy p
   LEFT
   JOIN user_policy up
     ON up.policy_id = p.policy_id
    AND up.username = 'Jbyrne'
  WHERE up.username IS NULL;

 +--------------------------+----------------------------+
 | policy_name              | policy_id                  |
 +--------------------------+----------------------------+
 | Bank Holiday Policy      | Bank_Holiday_Policyv1      |
 | Breaks                   | Breaksv2                   |
 | Collections Policy       | Collections_Policyv1       |
 | Company Car Share Policy | Company_Car_Share_Policyv1 |
 | Smoking Policy           | Smoking_Policyv2           |
 +--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_policy.Policy_Name, wp_policies.PolicyID
FROM wp_policy
right outer JOIN wp_policies ON wp_policy.Policy_ID = wp_policies.PolicyID
WHERE wp_policies.Username != 'byrnej'
AND wp_policy.Policy_ID IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY wp_policy.Policy_Name ASC
```

Comment: 0 results and I still need to pass through the username this sql is taken off a php page which acts like a report, there is a dropdown which passes through the username.

Answer (score 0):

if you try this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_policy.Policy_Name, wp_policy.Policy_ID, wp_policies.Username
FROM wp_policy
LEFT JOIN wp_policies ON 
wp_policy.Policy_ID=wp_policies.PolicyID AND wp_policies.Username='Jbyrne'
WHERE 1
ORDER BY wp_policy.Policy_Name ASC
```

it will show you which policies has been choosen or not for the specified user.
So after that, you need to modify the query like that and it will show only the lines that interess us...

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_policy.Policy_Name, wp_policy.Policy_ID
FROM wp_policy
LEFT JOIN wp_policies ON 
wp_policy.Policy_ID=wp_policies.PolicyID AND wp_policies.Username='Jbyrne'
WHERE wp_policies.PolicyID IS NULL 
ORDER BY wp_policy.Policy_Name ASC
```

The trick is to specify "wp_policies.Username='Jbyrne'" in the "ON" condition and after to specify wp_policies.PolicyID IS NULL in the "WHERE" condition.

Your first query was wrong because you've specified several conditions which are oposit. (sorry for my english...)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT wp_policy.Policy_ID
FROM wp_policy
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_policies
ON wp_policy.Policy_ID = wp_policies.PolicyID 
WHERE wp_policies.Username = 'byrnej'
AND wp_policies.PolicyID != wp_policy.Policy_ID 
ORDER BY wp_policy.Policy_ID ASC
```